# Join Field Management

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins, runtimeerror

I have not used the following tool, and am recieving the following error when trying to add a field to two of the following FC's below. Is this a syntax issue?

```
 import arcpy
 PlaceFC= filepath
 UAFC= filepath
 PSPlaces=filepath

arcpy.JoinField_management("UAFC","ID","PSPlaces","ID", {"Priority"})
arcpy.JoinField_management("PlaceFC", "ID", "PSPlaces","ID", {"Priority"})
```

[image]

Comment: Please always include error messages as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches by users with the same problem.

Comment: Don't forget to take the 2-minute [Tour] that is designed to introduce all users of this site to its focused Q&A format.  It can make all the difference when trying to frame questions that will attract potential answerers and enable quick answers to be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
arcpy.JoinField_management("UAFC","ID","PSPlaces","ID", {"Priority"})
arcpy.JoinField_management("PlaceFC", "ID", "PSPlaces","ID", {"Priority"})
```

Try:

```
arcpy.JoinField_management("UAFC","ID","PSPlaces","ID", ["Priority"])
arcpy.JoinField_management("PlaceFC", "ID", "PSPlaces","ID", ["Priority"])
```

The fifth parameter being a list should work.  You may also be able to just include the single field name without the square brackets that turn it into a list of one.

Comment: When changing the fifth parameter, I receive the following error, ExecuteError: ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset UAFC does not exist or is not supported ERROR 000732: Join Table: Dataset PSPlaces does not exist or is not supported

Comment: PSPlaces is in a SDE written as the following PSPlaces=r'Database Connections\FilePath' can it not have Database Connections, but the actually filepath?

Comment: That sounds like a new question but be sure to research the previous reports of [tag:error-000732] before asking it.  As a test, copy your tables out to a file geodatabase and see if your code works with them.  If it does then you know ArcSDE is what you need to look at, and if not you greatly widen your pool of potential answerers.

Comment: You can't link to a database outside of setting the env.workspace. Change `PSPlaces=r'Database Connections\FilePath']`to `arcpy.env.workspace = r'Database Connections\FilePath'`